Save File Selected from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to Variable or Create Copy to Local Storage
The Objective: Have the user select a pdf document, stored in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, to merge with another programmatically created pdf.
What I've Tried:

Saving the uri returned from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and getting File from this. However, the uri being stored is from the Content Provider content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000013540 and not the format I expected so when I try to get the file from it, I get a "Does Not Exist" error.

Copying the selected file from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to the downloads directory. I get a "No such file or directory" error with this.
     createTxtLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

     if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         val uri: Uri? = result.data?.data
         val resolver = requireContext().contentResolver
         val outDest = FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS  + "/Test.pdf"))
         val fi = FileInputStream(uri?.path)
         val origin = BufferedInputStream(fi)
         val out = BufferedOutputStream(outDest)
         try {
             origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
             println("hope this works")
         } catch (e: IOException) {
             println("error output stream")
         }
     }
 }



Can anyone please provide assistance on what the correct way to do this is? I've been stuck for a couple days now.

Replace val fi = FileInputStream(uri?.path) by val fi = resolver.openInputStream(uri). Never reference the path on a Uri, and never attempt to convert a Uri into a File.

@CommonsWare: Seriously, thank you for all your help on a couple of my questions. I have finally got it to work. I will accept answers on both questions.

Glad you got it working!

To get an InputStream on a Uri that you got from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, call openInputStream() on a ContentResolver.
Please bear in mind that ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT (and the rest of the Storage Access Framework) are not limited to the filesystem, so there is no way to convert a Uri to a File. Even if the Uri does point to something on the filesystem, you might not have rights to access it via the filesystem but do by using the Uri with ContentResolver.
